# java.net.SocketException after successful connection with webservice

Tags: android, web-services

I connected android application to the webservice. The code goes like that: printing to console flag1, retrieving information, printing to console flag 2. When program stops, flag1 is printed and less than half of information is retrieved. In logcat the error is "DEBUG/SntpClient(78): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol" and the second flag is not printed. 
What's wrong with it, here's the code:

```
                System.out.println("flag1");
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                while (bis.available() > 0) {
                    System.out.print((char)bis.read());
                }
                System.out.println("flag2");
```

Added:
logcat output:

```
10-06 20:55:15.585: INFO/System.out(460): flag1
10-06 20:55:33.136: DEBUG/SntpClient(78): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-06 21:00:33.146: DEBUG/SntpClient(78): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
10-06 21:03:22.656: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(473): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-06 21:03:22.656: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(473): CheckJNI is ON
10-06 21:03:23.206: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(473): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-06 21:03:23.326: DEBUG/dalvikvm(275): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 5% free 6302K/6595K, paused 5ms+3ms
```

Connection is created as:

```
URL url = new URI(address).toURL();
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

Edit:
When I want to read from inputstream not byte by byte but with buffer:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
System.out.println("flag1");
while ((n = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
System.out.write(buffer, 0, n);
System.out.println("flag2");
```

It prints flag1, half of the inputstream and then neither throws exception nor prints flag2:

```
10-06 21:26:09.016: INFO/System.out(804): flag1
10-06 21:26:09.356: INFO/System.out(804): less than half of the inputstream 
10-06 21:26:17.846: DEBUG/dalvikvm(195): GC_EXPLICIT freed 163K, 5% free 6829K/7175K, paused 9ms+3ms
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output and the code you use to create the connection

Comment: If you print out `bis.available` what does it say? also: I'm not sure reading byte by byte is what you really want to do here. You might want to get a whole array at once.